# How to get the field data

Tags: 7, nodes

Hi  i'm using entityreference, i hava an content type"test" that contain a field that refer to categorie and this categorie contain  a field_theme also referenced to another content type theme_test. On Theme_test i have a field entityreference that refer  to Criter and this last is  saved on Test Finally on an other field let's name it  recap.

```
array(19) {
  ["#theme"]=>
  string(5) "field"
  ["#weight"]=>
  string(1) "6"
  ["#title"]=>
  string(18) "suivi pédagogique"
  ["#access"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["#label_display"]=>
  string(5) "above"
  ["#view_mode"]=>
  string(4) "full"
  ["#language"]=>
  string(3) "und"
  ["#field_name"]=>
  string(11) "field_suivi"
  ["#field_type"]=>
  string(15) "entityreference"
  ["#field_translatable"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["#entity_type"]=>
  string(4) "node"
  ["#bundle"]=>
  string(4) "test"
  ["#object"]=>
  object(stdClass)#80 (35) {
    ["vid"]=>
    string(3) "500"
    ["uid"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["title"]=>
    string(25) "test1_2021-08-20 16:02:29"
    ["log"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["status"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["comment"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["promote"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["sticky"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["nid"]=>
    string(8) "10485403"
    ["type"]=>
    string(4) "test"
    ["language"]=>
    string(3) "und"
    ["created"]=>
    string(10) "1629468149"
    ["changed"]=>
    string(10) "1629468149"
    ["tnid"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["translate"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["revision_timestamp"]=>
    string(10) "1629468149"
    ["revision_uid"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["field_id_externe"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["field_categories"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["und"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        array(3) {
          ["target_id"]=>
          string(2) "20"
          ["entity"]=>
          object(stdClass)#96 (30) {
            ["vid"]=>
            string(2) "20"
            ["uid"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["title"]=>
            string(7) "r489_1A"
            ["log"]=>
            string(0) ""
            ["status"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["comment"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["promote"]=>
            string(1) "0"
            ["sticky"]=>
            string(1) "0"
            ["nid"]=>
            string(2) "20"
            ["type"]=>
            string(9) "categorie"
            ["language"]=>
            string(3) "und"
            ["created"]=>
            string(10) "1625752758"
            ["changed"]=>
            string(10) "1629454614"
            ["tnid"]=>
            string(1) "0"
            ["translate"]=>
            string(1) "0"
            ["revision_timestamp"]=>
            string(10) "1629454614"
            ["revision_uid"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["field_famille"]=>
            array(0) {
            }
            ["field_ut"]=>
            array(0) {
            }
            ["field_id_externe"]=>
            array(1) {
              ["und"]=>
              array(1) {
                [0]=>
                array(3) {
                  ["value"]=>
                  string(7) "r489-1A"
                  ["format"]=>
                  NULL
                  ["safe_value"]=>
                  string(7) "r489-1A"
                }
              }
            }
            ["field_theme"]=>
            array(1) {
              ["und"]=>
              array(2) {
                [0]=>
                array(1) {
                  ["target_id"]=>
                  string(8) "10485206"
                }
                [1]=>
                array(1) {
                  ["target_id"]=>
                  string(8) "10485236"
                }
              }
            }
```

I want to display  Criter by theme on node "test" programmatically but  idon't know how, i google it but no one have some idea  for Three level of referenced entity.

Thanks to All :)

Comment: What version of Drupal are you using?

Comment: I'm using Drupal7 @shelane